# Replacing words in a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to replace words in a string using mssql.
Query:

```sql
UPDATE VS_48538  
SET name = REPLACE(name, '%[N]eptun[ ][-]kód%', 'Neptunkód') 
WHERE name LIKE '%[N]eptun[ ][-]kód%'
```

What I'd like to change is `cc neptun -kód dd`, (just this part:  **neptun -kód --> Neptunkód**). Replace is not working.

Comment: `REPLACE` doesn't accept patterns. SQL Server, in truth, doesn't have *any* built-in support for pattern replacement. Though why are you not just using `'neptun -kód'` as the literal to match?

Comment: umm, `replace(name,N'neptun -kód',N'Neptunkód')`?

Comment: [SQL Server Replace Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) I don't know that you need `REPLACE` here though. Will the value you want to remove always be 'neptun -kód' and will you always replace it with 'Neptunkód'? If so, you can just do `... SET name = 'Neptunkód' WHERE name = 'neptun -kód';`

Comment: As the OP states that (at least) one of the values they want to changeis `''cc neptun -kód dd'`, then your `WHERE` clause won't find that row, @ClearlyClueless .

Comment: @ClearlyClueless i need the replace i cant update the row. Actually i have sentences in it.
In oracle it looks like:
set c_name = regexp_replace(c_name, '[Nn]eptun[ -]kód', 'Neptunkód')

Comment: @Larnu There wasn't much stated in the OP in general and much of the question was left open to interpretation. Perhaps additional context in the OP and a sample data set would yeild better answers?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
replace(name,N'neptun -kód',N'Neptunkód')
```

Credits to @George Menoutis.